# JQuery calls document onload also

Tags: jquery

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".challengeform").hide(); 
    $("#sendchallengebutton").hide();   
    $("#successchallenge").hide();
    console.log("Hide all");
});

$("#challengebutton").click(function() {
    $(".challengeform").show(); 
    $("#sendchallengebutton").show();   
    console.log("Unhide some");
});
```

Simple. But when I click the challenge button, it shows everything I want it to show for about 1 second, then it hides it again. In the console log I get "Hide all", then when I click #challengebutton it says "Unhide some", then "Hide all" again. I just want to know what is wrong with how this code is. I think I could maybe find an alternate route on my own, but I want to learn the reason. If anyone knows I would love the help

Here is my entire html page. It is in rails so it does contain erb

```
<h1>Profile</h1>

<h1><%= @user.username %></h1>

<h1>Level: <%= @summonerlevel %></h1>


<a href="" id="challengebutton">Challenge</a>

<%= form_tag("../challenges", method: "post", class:"challengeform") do %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "Start time") %>
<%= select_tag(:starttime, options_for_select([["6am", 6], ["7am", 7], ["8am", 8], ["9am", 9], ["10am", 10], ["11am", 11], ["12pm", 12], ["1pm", 13], ["2pm", 14], ["3pm", 15], ["4pm", 16], ["5pm", 17], ["6pm", 18], ["7pm", 19], ["8pm", 20], ["9pm", 21], ["10pm", 22], ["11pm", 23], ["12am", 24], ["1am", 1], ["2am", 2], ["3am", 3], ["4am",4 ], ["5am", 5]], selected: :option )) %>
<%= label_tag(:q, "End time") %>
<%= select_tag(:endtime, options_for_select([["6am", 6], ["7am", 7], ["8am", 8], ["9am", 9], ["10am", 10], ["11am", 11], ["12pm", 12], ["1pm", 13], ["2pm", 14], ["3pm", 15], ["4pm", 16], ["5pm", 17], ["6pm", 18], ["7pm", 19], ["8pm", 20], ["9pm", 21], ["10pm", 22], ["11pm", 23], ["12am", 24], ["1am", 1], ["2am", 2], ["3am", 3], ["4am",4 ], ["5am", 5]], selected: :option )) %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :challengeuser, @user.username %>
<% end %>
<a href="" id="sendchallengebutton">Send Challenge</a>
<p id="successchallenge">Challenge Sent!</p>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".challengeform").hide(); 
        $("#sendchallengebutton").hide();   
        $("#successchallenge").hide();
        console.log("Hide all");
    });

    $("#challengebutton").click(function() {
        $(".challengeform").show(); 
        $("#sendchallengebutton").show();   
        console.log("Unhide some");
    });



</script>
```

Comment: Post your HTML please. And a jsFiddle.net example may help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was because the href tag challenge button was causing the page to reload.

You need to change the challenge button link to be:

```
<a  id="challengebutton" href="#" onclick="return false">Challenge</a>
```

Here is a jsfiddle of your code working : http://jsfiddle.net/jbekjn4o/

Answer (score 0):

You need to return false inside of your click event.

```
$("#challengebutton").click(function() {
    $(".challengeform").show(); 
    $("#sendchallengebutton").show();   
    console.log("Unhide some");
    return false;
});
```

Since your #challengebutton is a link, clicking on it is causing a reload of the page (empty href attribute)